# how to detect whether an object is inside something in html5 phaser

Tags: html5-canvas, phaser-framework, isometric

I am working in a game using Phaser.

The idea of the game is to check whether the objects fit inside the chest while keeping the objects appear as if it where a 3D game using isometric.

How can I check whether the objects are inside the chest? I have tried to detect overlap but it is not working accurately

Comment: Give us a minimal working example.

Comment: You'll also want to include which version of Phaser you're using (CE or 3).